# Adding events from YouTube to GoogleCalendar

Tags: youtube, google-calendar

I was trying to use the "Add to calendar" option from a YouTube event.
In the options to add to a calendar, it is only showing my Birthday calendar.
Other calendars are not displayed in the option.

1. Why are my other calendars not displayed and how do I add it to other calendar?
2. Also whenever I attend a event in Google+ it automatically gets added to the Birthday calendar.

   Why is this and how do I change this setting?

Comment: I would expect it to go against your "main" account calendar (i.e., the calendar you can't delete). Is that, perhaps, the only calendar you're sharing?

Comment: @AlE. I have about 5 calendar and have not shared anything - they are all private. The Birthday calendar is also not public, but that gets displayed in the options.